# How to delete conditions from Bigcommerce Product Rule

Tags: bigcommerce

The Bigcommerce API documentation for [Product Rules](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products/rules) says the following in the Update a Product Rule section:

> Updates an existing product rule. NOTE: if you include a conditions object array, its contents will be appended to any existing conditions. This operation does not overwrite existing conditions.

I need to delete existing conditions from a rule, but I can't figure out a way to do it. No matter what you pass in for conditions, it just gets appended to the conditions that are already there. You also can't clear out the conditions first, because the request is rejected if the conditions array is empty.

Is there any way to remove conditions from a rule besides recreating the entire rule?

Answer (score 0):

First, BigCommerce is a *little* wonky.

I think your best bet is to simply go the manual route, with a 4 step process:

1. Ge the original rule and store it in a variable, via:

   ```
   GET /stores/{store_hash}/v2/products/{product_id}/rules/{id}
   ```
2. Then Delete the original rule via:

   ```
   DELETE /stores/{store_hash}/v2/products/{product_id}/rules/{id}
   ```
3. Now, edit the JSON response you store with the GET method to reflect the changes you want to make,
4. Finally, re-create the rule with your changes via:

   ```
   POST /stores/{store_hash}/v2/products/{product_id}/rules/{id}
   ```

passing your edited JSON response as parameters.

---

Let me know if this helps and if you have nay other questions.